# Entity is not mapping to table name properly

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a Entity with name "InventoryVenue" for the table "Inventory_Venue".

When I'm trying to insert data, entity manager pointing to "InventoryVenue" instead of "Inventory_Venue" which is not exists in database.

Comment: You need to update schema first,It will create all db structure in db.

Comment: Can you please elaborate so i can understand it correctly please?

Comment: you should apply this command  for update schema.

"php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force"

Comment: Please give what exact error are you facing ?  If it cache related please do "php app/console cache:clear"

Comment: Sorry but it throwing error as

Comment: [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                                     
  The table with name 'mytable_07_11.instructor_venue' already exists.

Comment: Please post your code! In particular, you Entity InventoryVenue and the place where you use it with the entity manager. Thanks!

Comment: any update please?

Answer (score 0):

[This is my entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61J7H.png)

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBeOP.png)

Here entity not pointing to the actual table.